# Catching Gstreamer WARNING messages

Tags: logging, error-handling, warnings, gstreamer

I am writing a Gstreamer application and trying to catch warning messages for logging purposes. Yes I know Gstreamer has its own logger but what I need is a C code which catches general messages without relying on any bash command. I can catch end-of-stream (EOS), error and STATE_CHANGED messages properly but I can't catch the warning messages. An example error message catch code is as follows taken from the [Gstreamer's site](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstMessage.html#gst-message-parse-error).

```
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
    gchar  *debug;
    GError *error;

    gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
    g_printerr ("***ERROR*** from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), error->message);
    g_printerr ("***Debugging*** info: %s\n", (debug) ? debug : "none");
    g_error_free (error);
    g_free (debug);

    rc = 201;
    g_main_loop_quit (loop);
    break;
}
```

There is a `gst_message_parse_warning` function as well and I tried the following code snippet to catch the warning messages but it doesn't work unfortunately and I am unable to find anything on the internet so far. I could really use some help.

```
    case GST_MESSAGE_WARNING: {
    gchar *debug;
    GError *error;
    gst_message_parse_warning (msg, &error, &debug);
    g_printerr ("***WARNING*** from element %s: %s", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), error->message);
    g_printerr ("***Debugging*** info: %s", (debug) ? debug : "none");
    g_error_free (error);
    g_free (debug);
    break;
}
```

Comment: I used the same case, for logging the warning and error messages and it worked perfectly, Actually i attached a bus to my pipeline, and then in call back function of bus, i parse the messages. And it worked perfectly. How you are parsing the messages?

Comment: @PrasanthKumarArisetti I also have a bus attached to pipeline to watch for the messages and a call back function of bus as well. We are probably doing the exact same thing. Maybe could you post your call back function so that I can check if there are differences? I am using the parser of the Gstreamer for this in the link above.